# Golang Pointer Analysis to determine if buffer has been flushed

Tags: pointers, go, static-analysis

I'm new to pointer analysis and static analysis in general, I hope someone can give me a brief answer and push me in the right direction.

Basically what I want to achieve is to do static analysis of Go source, looking after potential buggy code, e.g. forgetting to Flush() a buffer.

Its maybe trivial to check after an Flush() operation on a buffer variable in a single function. But as in the code under, it´s harder to detect that the buffer actually is closed in another function called.

How can one nicely do static checking to solve this, I can only think of using the Go tools pointer package [1](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/pointer#example-package), but it´s not easy to get grasp on the documentation.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    w := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World")
    closeBuffer(w)
}

func closeBuffer(buf *bufio.Writer) {
    buf.Flush()
}
```